# Excessive elements in latex longtable output when more than one row is used in Hmisc

Tags: r, latex, hmisc

Two very similar commands produce different headers in `latex()` from `Hmisc`. The question is: how to get rid of the excessive header that is repeated right in the first page of `longtable`?

```
latex(data.frame(1:10), caption="Title", longtable=TRUE, rowname=NULL)
```

[image]

```
latex(data.frame(1:10, 10:1), caption="Title", longtable=TRUE, rowname=NULL)
```

[image]